# Flutter Markdown: How do you top align text in a table?

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter markdown, and for this example, the text in the first column isn't aligned to the top of the table cell. Is there a way to do this?

```dart
Markdown(
              data: """
|   |   |
|---|---|
|  **09.00** | Test thing about this really long column that should wrap when doingstusfff jasijifjsai jgisajgisajigfaj jsaigfjsaigfjsai jgisajijisjgijasigfj  |
""",
              styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
                textAlign: WrapAlignment.start,
                h2: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                code: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontFamily: "monospace",
                ),
                codeblockPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                tableBorder: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0),
                tableColumnWidth: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                tableCellsPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10),
                tableHeadAlign: TextAlign.start,
              ),
              onTapLink: _markdownLinkHandler,
            )
```

I expect the text to be at the top of the cell rather than in the center